# Group centering for interactions with within-between mixed panel model

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, centering

I need to update a model to incorporate an interaction between a time-invariant categorical variable and a demeaned time-variant variable. I'm unsure about how to correctly use group-mean centering over the time-invariant variable (3 population levels). I want to confirm whether my data preparation for updating this model makes sense, and I have questions about interactions and unbalanced data.

**My data:** My panel data consists of 5,500 cities (**ID**) in Brazil that are surveyed for seven years to measure how active a social assistance institution (**CMAS**) is in each city-year. I'm testing whether a more active CMAS reduces infant mortality (**Infant_Mortality**). The current model excludes all city observations below 20k residents, because I don't expect the CMAS to reduce infant mortality in small cities.

My current panel model (without controls) is a Poisson mixed model with random intercepts for the city; and the activity-level of the CMAS is transformed to show within- and between-variation as described [here](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/articles/demean.html) and/or [here](https://panelr.jacob-long.com/). I prepare the within-between transformations manually using R, then I run the model in Stata, because it won't converge in panelr or glmer. This is the current model:

$y_i{_t} = \beta0 + \beta1 (CMAS_i{_t} - \overline{CMAS_i}) + \beta2 \overline{CMAS_i} + u_i + \epsilon_i{_t}$

In the updated model I want to test the effect of within-variation of the CMAS ($\beta1$ in the current model) at three time-invariant, categorical levels of city population (**Pop_Group**). In this way, I can show the effect of the within-variation of the CMAS in small vs medium vs large cities.

In order to facilitate interpretation of the interaction between the within-variation of the CMAS ($\beta1$ in the current model) and **Pop_Group**, I need to grand-mean-center the CMAS variables, but I'm unsure if I did this in a way to properly account for the three categories of **Pop_Group**.

**What I did:** Prior to creating the within- and between-variation variables for the CMAS, I centered the CMAS over the three **Pop_Group** categories. I grouped the CMAS city-year values by the **Pop_Group** they belong to. Within each **Pop_Group**, the mean for all CMAS values is zero. I did this in order to be able to interpret the main coefficients for **Pop_Group** categories as between-unit differences in **Pop_Group** at mean (zero) values of **CMAS** (for both within- and between-variation variables. (See below for more details)

First, does it make sense to grand-mean center by **Pop_Group** THEN create within- and between variables like this? Any issues?

Second, does the interaction of interest (c.CMAS_within##i.Pop_Group below) become biased if I don't also interact CMAS_between and i.Pop_Group? It seems like the group-mean centering of the CMAS would create some bias without the second interaction. Perhaps the inclusion of **Pop_Group** already accounts for this without the interaction.

Third, the control variables I use in later models introduce missing values for some city-year observations. This means my data becomes unbalanced, and the precise city-year observations included for each model are very slightly different for each model I run. Should I assume I must perform the group-centering and within-between transformations using the precise observations for each version of the model?

This is the code I use in R to group center then create within-between variables:

```
library(dplyr)

clean <- data %>%
  group_by(Pop_Group) %>%          # this is my three population groups
  mutate(
    CMAS_c = CMAS - mean(CMAS, na.rm=T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%                 # Now I group at the ID for within-between transformations
  mutate(
    CMAS_within = CMAS_c - mean(CMAS_c , na.rm=T),
    CMAS_between = mean(CMAS_c , na.rm=T)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I then use the data in a model like this in Stata (controls excluded here). Remember that Pop_Group is time-invariant:

```
mepoisson Infant_Mortality c.CMAS_within##i.Pop_Group CMAS_between##i.Pop_Group , exposure(Annual_Births) || ID: , vce(robust) irr
```

I could provide this in GLMER notation if that would help, but it's a basic within-between Poisson mixed model aside from the interactions (##).

Comment: Rather than provide links and code to show what you did, please provide an explanation in plain english about what you did, and why. Otherwise I doubt you will get useful (or any) answers. Also I don't know what "*as I introduce the controls, I lose a few city-year observations here and there*" means, and also "*I don't expect this institution to work very well in small cities*"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited for clarification. I hope it makes more sense now.